# Any way to keep this earnings parameter from re-painting?

Tags: pine-script

I have this code as part of my strategy. It worked perfectly on TSLA this week with one caveat. A few hours after earnings, this parameter went from false to true and it remains true. Because of this, my strategy re-painted the trade immediately before earnings. i.e. There was no trade due to the earnings parameter being false, then a few hours after earnings the parameter suddenly became true (even the bars right before earnings), and then the strategy re-painted as if it had entered a trade.

This parameter is basically saying, "don't take a trade if earnings are within 48 hours"

```
Earnings = earnings.future_time
Time = time
NoEarningsIn48 = (Earnings - Time) > 172800000
plotchar(NoEarningsIn48, "No Earnings", display=display.data_window)
```

I am assuming the problem lies within the earnings.future_time parameter.